# Who is this person depicted on a wall in Estonia?

Tags: identification, photography, estonia

[image: Man's face painted on a wall]

Took this photo in Estonia... anybody know who the person pictured is?

Comment: some more information would help.  what city was this taken in?  what type of building was it?  do you have the address?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the contributor of [this](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/artwork-443053) similar Shutterstock image?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Johan Laidoner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johan_Laidoner), an important military and political figure from eartly 20th century.